# Demandware - Pipeline not found for current domain

Tags: pipeline, demandware

I already made pipeline. Which is working fine. Suddenly it give error like

> 2015-12-18 02:39:08.091 GMT] ERROR system.core ISH-CORE-2368 Sites-SiteGenesis-Site core Storefront [uuid] [request-id]-0-00 [timestamp]
>  "Error executing pipeline: Hello com.demandware.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException:
> Pipeline not found (Hello) for current domain (Sites-SiteGenesis-Site)"

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using studio? Have you tried re-uploading your cartridges to the server? The message also states that the pipeline `Hello` is not found, are you sure that `Hello` is the name of the pipeline, and not `HelloWorld`?

Comment: Yes using Eclipse - Demandware extension. It's Sandbox which is shared by other people. Yes it's confirm name is Hello, yesterday it's working fine. today it's not working

Comment: Right click your project in the Explorer, click Demandware -> Upload Cartridge, can you post a screen cap of your PipelineEditor?

Comment: Uploaded Cartridge 2 times. Still same issue :(

Comment: Screen cap of your project tree, and the pipeline editor you see in eclipse?

Comment: Yes can see & it's auto sync to server

Comment: I mean please take a screen capture and upload the image so I may see.

Comment: Image is added in question

Comment: If you click 'Change upload staging directory,' does this match what you have setup in BussinessManager?

Comment: And thanks for the screen cap, I was also looking for the project explorer on the left too please.

Comment: Has your cartridge path changed? Might want to check that too. You said it was a shared instance, someone may have removed your cartridge from the path.

Comment: Finally Got it. It's path issue. Works now :)

Comment: Woooo, glad to help. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the event that your pipeline can not be found for the selected domain, please go trough and verify all of the following:

1. **Double check Pipeline-Node naming**

Pipeline URLs are generated by their name and your desired entry node, in this scenario, I would expect a file named *Hello.xml* in you cartridge's pipeline directory, and a start node named *Start*, would be accessed via *{instanceURL}/on/demandware.store/Sites-mySite-Site/Hello-Start*

2. **Try and force upload of your cartridges**

Occasionally the files on the server will not be updated correctly when a save is made; to force an update, right click your project, click *Demandware* > *Upload Cartridges*

3. **Check your Cartridge Path**

If you are using a shared instance, or your instance is re-provisioned, you may need to check your cartridge path to be sure your custom cartridge(s) are still there.

4. **Check your Code Versions**

Occasionally you may increment / change your code version - if you do, make sure that the path you select in Studio is the one that you have selected in Business Manager.

5. **Tech Support**

Should you still have issues following the four steps above, please file a support ticket and the tech-support team will be able to provide you with more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in SFCC sfra custom cartridge, my form **controller js** file was in **subfolder** of **controllers** folder so taking it a **level up** i.e., directly in **controllers** folder resolved the issue.